# Why are protic acids not used for the formation of thioacetals?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, carbonyl-compounds

The standard procedure for protecting a carbonyl group as an acetal uses dry acid, such as $\ce{TsOH}$, but when forming a thioacetal, the Lewis acid $\ce{BF3}$ seems to be the catalyst of choice. For example, see Corey and Seebach's original demonstration of dithiane acidity: [*Org. Synth.* **1970**, *50*, 72](http://www.orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=CV6P0556).

Is there any particular theoretical or practical reason why this is the case? I am guessing that the boron trifluoride coordinates exclusively to the harder oxygen atom, making it a better leaving group and hence favouring the formation of products (since the reaction is under thermodynamic control). However, I don't see any reason why acid wouldn't be able to do the job equally well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pKa/leaving group ability between alcohols and thiols may have something to do with it.

> Alcohol pKa around 17, thiol around 13.

As you pointed out the whole reaction is in equilibrium. But in the case of the thioacetal, after the initial addition theres a strong driving force to kick back out the sulfur to reform the carbonyl rather than committing to the thioacetyl formation since the sulfur is a relatively stable leaving group.

Protic acids are almost always wet, and as such the water would prevent the reaction, whereas Lewis acids are generally either neat, or in ethereal solutions.